# How to serialize JSON array as a numbered/indexed JSON using jackson?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have an array of objects of following class

```
public class Person
{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    //Rest of the getters and setters

}

public class Data
{
    private ArrayList<Person> persons;

    public Data()
    {
            persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
            Person p1 = new Person(1L, "walter");
            Person p2 = new Person(2L, "white");
            persons.add(p1);
            persons.add(p2);
    }
}
```

Now if I create the object Data in my program and serialize this `Data` object using jackson, it will give me the following JSON.

```
{
    "data": {
        "persons": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "walter"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "white"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

is there any way to serialize this object into following numbered/indexed JSON?

```
{
    "data": {
        "persons": {
            "1": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "walter"
            },
            "2": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "white"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not make `ArrayList<Person> persons;` a `HashMap<Integer, Person>`  or a `LinkedHashMap<Integer, Person>` if order matters?

Comment: @Epicblood : order doesn't matter here. I just want a numbered array. Basically this is just an example that I have written. In my use case, I have an incoming data in array format but I have to write that data in indexed/numbred format.

Comment: i don't think jackson has that feature, I'd put the array you get through a for each loop and turn it into a hashmap

Comment: Looks like that is the only solution I have got.

Comment: I updated my answer, looks like it is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>I don't think that is something you can just tell Jackson to do.</del>

The easiest solution I can think of is to turn the array you get into a `HashMap<Integer, Person>` and pass that into jackson.

If order matters (you want "1" to be before "2") then you can use a `LinkedHashMap<Integer, Person>`

Something like this:

```
HashMap<Integer, Person> pMap = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++){
    pMap.put(i, persons.get(i));
}
```

**Edit: 
Turns out you can do it, you just have to write the serializer yourself**<sub>[*1*](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization)</sub>**, so you would do something like:**

```
public class PersonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Person> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Person person, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) 
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject(String.valueOf(i));
        jgen.writeNumberField("id", i);
        jgen.writeStringField("name", person.getName());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

You can tell jackson to use this serializer by simply adding an antotation to the Person class

```
@JsonSerialize(using = PersonSerializer.class)
public class Person
{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    //Rest of the getters and setters

}
```